# sharing one def function among multiple urls in django

Tags: python, django

I have one def function that I would like to use to handle two urls. I need the function to behave slightly differently depending on which url is called.  Is there a way to add inputs to the def function from urls.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pass an extra option to the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) that it can check to see which urlconf it was invoked from.